# Is the keyboard height of iPad and iPad Mini the same in portrait?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a scrollview which ContentSize will be increased by keyboard height when keyboard is activated. On iPhone I am adding 216 for keyboard height. And for 9.7 inch iPad I know the height is 264.

But what is the height of keyboard in portrait on iPad Mini?

Comment: Why are you hardcoding these sizes at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all write tis code to get notification when keyboard appears in viewdidload:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

then write following code to get full dimensions of your keyboard (in any iOS device).

```
    - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
   NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
   CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    NSLog(@"height of keyboard is %f",kbSize.height);
}
```

this method will be called automatically when the keyboard will appear. Get dimensions of any iOS device dynamically like this.

Comment: You should use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` otherwise you'll have problems w/ some asian keyboards.